# How can I disable the animation for a Bootstrap 4 collapse collapsing / showing with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a big Bootstrap 4 collapsable element. I want it to be able to collapse / show manually like normal.

But I also want it to collapse when a condition is met, so I use this function:

```
if (condition) {
  $('#myCollapse').collapse();
}
```

It works fine, but every time I change pages it collapses with the animation that takes a while. I want to remove this animation so it just instantly collapse.

I tried:

- Hiding it. Doesn't work as I need to trigger the state change from "shown" to "collapsed" for other purposes and hiding it doesn't trigger that.
- Using $.support.transition = false; but it doesn't seem to work and it says it's deprecated.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You hide it and then you set the status as if it was collapsed

Comment: If I hide it, and then change status as collapsed, the collapse stops working, it's always hidden.

Comment: And if I hide it, change status as collapsed, then show it, it uncollapses instead of keeping the collapsed status.